# Entity Framework 4: Can I handle exception at context level

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I want to handle a very specific EF exception: conversion overflows.
I want to know if it is possible to configure the context to execute predefined code block\method when this specific exception occurs.

if it is possible to handle unhandled ef exception at context it is also good for me since I'll be able to investigate the exception content and respond as required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use the log4net or elmah to log the error and then you can check what the actual errors  comes under.

Comment: i want to do something specific to this exception. log4net and elmah sounds to me like a more general solution

Comment: We use log4net.  All we use it for is logging messages & errors.  If you want to do something else with the exception, it's not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put the error handling in the context object.  I tend to place that code in my Presentation Layer, though it be placed in the Repository Layer, depending on what you want to do with the exception.  The code that is emitted for each entity class and function import will get regenerated each time you update the model from the database, wiping out any changes you make to them.

But the context class is itself a partial, so you could add a file with another partial definition of the class to your project & define a method in it to it that you call in your catch blocks.

Comment: db created manually and the entities are linked to tables using data annotations. is your comment still relevant to this architechure?

Comment: I have never used code first EF, so I can't answer your question, but I think what I suggested in the answer is still good practice, even so.  In my code, I have a method in another class that is called by each catch block in the Presentation Layer, because what I want to do with the exception can only be done in the Presentation Layer.

Comment: i already use log4net so this exception is logged. i wanted to know if I can handle it as I mentioned in the question. thanks anyways